# Reading SWF file code from C#

Tags: c#, flash

I have a site that accepts flash files to be uploaded in my site and i need to check the SWF file uploaded to check for certain code if it exists or not to put it in the SWF file so i need to read or deassembly the SWF file and read its code from C#.Net
is there any way to do that ?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could utilize http://flasm.sourceforge.net/.

Comment: I need code in C# that can help me check that the SWF file uploaded contains specific code and if not i need to add this code to the SWF file(This code make the flash file linkable and directs to the right URL) can u help me find C# code???

Comment: I need explicity a C# code that enables me to check that the SWF file is including specific code in it's first frame.Can u give me a code for that plz?

Answer (score 1):

If your flash version is not greater than 7 then you could use this one  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16834/How-to-create-a-simple-SWF-decompiler-with-the-Swf